# Tracking down sheet music for "God Is" by James Cleveland

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I am not sure where to ask this question, but the Stack Exchange sites have been a good resource for me for other interests that I have, so I am hoping that I drilled down to the right level here to ask this question.

There is a particular Gospel Song that I would like to learn to play, "God Is" by James Cleveland & the SoCal Community Choir.  As I can read sheet music reasonably, I was hoping I could find the sheet music to this song.  However, I can't find the sheet music anywhere for this particular piece, which is strange to me because it is a reasonably popular and standard song in most choirs that I have seen or been associated with.

Would anyone here know where to begin to hunt down the sheet music for this song?

Comment: I found some references saying that ntimemusic.com used to have it.  Perhaps you should contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Google it.

[A Choir Director's Guide to "God Is" by James Cleveland](http://www.squidoo.com/james-cleveland-god-is)

http://www.squidoo.com/james-cleveland-god-is

> Songwriter and publisher info
>
> "God Is" was written by Robert James
>   Fryson. The publisher of the song is Glori-Gospel Music, according to
>   BMI (here's the BMI listing).

GLORI-GOSPEL MUSIC

CAE/IPI #: 43830101

Phone:  (516) 221-9414

GLORI-GOSPEL MUSIC

A DIVISION OF GLORI RECORD INC

C/O STEVEN HERMAN

331 FRANKEL BLVD

MERRICK, NY 11566

Comment: I had previously visited that sites after conducting a google search.  They List a piano tutorial, but I would rather see the sheet music and go from there.  Thanks for the info.  I will probably end contacting that company and seeing if I can't get the piano sheet music.

Answer (score 0):

This song is in a couple of hymnals - Only the choir parts, not the solos

Zion Still Sings - #134
African American Heritage Hymnal - #134